# I want to display my output in the command prompt in a specific format [MATLAB]

Tags: matlab, format, text-formatting

So I wrote code to display a certain row of a matrix depending on the user input. However, I need to display it in the following format:

```
Al (--%): 

Cu (--%): 

Mg (--%): 

Mn (--%):

Si (--%): 

Zn (--%):
```

I need to find a way to display the numbers from the output row in that format in the command window. Here's my code:

```
%alloy compositions
a=[4.4 1.5 0.6 0 0; 0 1 0 0.6 0; 0 1.4 0 0 4.5; 1.6 2.5 0 0 5.6; 
0 0.3 0 7 0];
%alloy compositions 

A2042=a(1, :); 
A6061=a(2, :); 
A7005=a(3, :);
A7075=a(4, :);



prompt='Please enter an alloy code: ';  
   percents=input(prompt)
```

Which indeed outputs the row I want, I just need to fit it into the format given. So if I get the output row `[4.4 1.5 0.6 0 0]`, I would need an output of

```
Al (4.4%): 
Cu (1.5%): 
Mg (0.6%): 
Mn (0%):
Si (0%):
```

Does anyone know how to do this? I thank you all in advance.

Comment: How about ? Disp('Al( num2str(outputrow(1)) %)') and similarly for the others - Disp('Cu( num2str(outputrow(2)) %)') etc

Comment: Consider accepting one of the answers below if they have helped you.

Answer (score 5):

```
metals = {'Al'; 'Cu';'Mg';'Mn';'Si'}; % metal names
percentages = [4.4;1.5;0.6;0;0]; % Corresponding percentages
Formatspec = ('%s (%1.1f%%):'); % Format specifier for your string
for ii = 1:numel(percentages)
    str = sprintf(Formatspec,metals{ii},percentages(ii)); % Create a string
    disp(str) % Display the string
end

Al (4.4%):
Cu (1.5%):
Mg (0.6%):
Mn (0.0%):
Si (0.0%):
```

The loop's a bit tricky and ugly, but my `sprintf` complained about not being defined for `cell-type` inputs.

The interesting line here is `('%s (%1.1f%%):')`, which specifies your format to first contain a string (`%s`), then a space and a bracket opening, subsequently a floating-point number with 1 number before and one after the decimal separator. Finally close off with your closing bracket and colon.

Comment: @GameOfThrows thanks! I actually had to look up the code to print a percentage sign...

Comment: Ah yes, I sometimes get lost when going back to matlab where % usually is modulo in other languages :(

Comment: I wanted to do just `\%` because LaTeX :D

Answer (score 1):

Just a little addition to [Adriaan's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5211833/adriaan) answer:

If you want to keep the string in a variable (not just display it), you should change this part of his code:

```
for ii = 1:numel(percentages)
    str = sprintf(Formatspec,metals{ii},percentages(ii)); % Create a string
    disp(str) % Display the string
end
```

to:

```
percent_show=repmat(' ',[numel(percentages) 10]);
for ii = 1:numel(percentages)
    str = sprintf(Formatspec,metals{ii},percentages(ii)); % Create a string
    percent_show(ii,:)=str;
end

disp(percent_show) % Display the string
```

Comment: You might want to initialise `percent_show` instead of appending it each iteration. Good addition!